# Calculating E[log(g(x))]

Tags: expected-value

Let $g(x)=a+bx$ and let $x$ have known distribution $f(x)$, say.

Is it possible to calculate:

$$\mathbb{E}[\log(g(x))] = \int f(x) \log{g(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x= \int \log(a + b x) f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x?$$

Many thanks for all of the help in advance.

Comment: Well, you do need to worry about the possibility that $g(x)$ could have negative value so that the logarithm is undefined (in the real number system), but if this is not an issue, then Yes, you can calculate $E[\log(g(x)]$ using the formula you have written down.

Comment: Yes, I should have said g(x)>0. I also should have been more clear, I know that it is possible to calculate the value, but what I meant to ask is whether there is a closed form expression which does not include the integral.

Comment: I do not believe that a closed-form expression exists for arbitrary distributions, though for particular cases, the computation would be relatively easy and one could write down a formula for future reference, e.g. $a+bX$ is uniformly distributed on $[\alpha, \beta]$ where $0 < \alpha < \beta$.